# What Islamic schools offer online degree or courses in fully learning dream interpretation, and among other things related to Islam

Tags: school

I’m unable to find any online schoolsthat offer a degree in dream interpretation or courses to fully learn dream interpretations. Mainly because I don’t really know any Islamic schools. I also don’t know any scholars that do. I know that you must know if the person is engaged in haram and among other things in order to interpret. However I’m interested in dream interpretation and want to earn a degree in this field. I really want to earn something so that I can show my mosques in my area or near my area that I have a degree in this and I’m willing to do this to interpret their dream. Also I want to earn a degree or learn courses related to other things in Islam.

Comment: I doubt that there would be any, dream interpretations is a highly subjective topic and resources for it are rare in Islamic corpus.

Comment: Do you know a scholar that can teach this?

Comment: Which resources do you think that scholar would depend on?

Comment: if you found a school teaching dream interpretation online you can safely assume it is fake, since the Islamic understanding is that dream-Interpretation needs one-to-one situations and enough knowledge about the person whose dreams shall be interpreted. In other words you can't safely interprete dreams without meeting the person in real life and communicate with him/her